# What is the difference between int -> int -> int and (int*int) -> int in SML?

Tags: functional-programming, sml, smlnj, ml

I have noticed that there are 2 ways of defining functions in SML. For example if you take the add function, these are the two ways:

```
fun add x y = x+y;

fun add(x,y) = x+y;
```

The first method creates the function type as:

```
val add = fn : int -> int -> int
```

The second one creates the function type as:

```
val add = fn : int * int -> int
```

What is the difference between these two types for the same function? And also why are there two types for the same function?

Comment: In the case of int -> int -> int , Is it because of currying where add first takes one int, returns another function that takes another int and return final int?

Comment: https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse341/09au/notes/notes07.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we remove the syntactic sugar from your two definitions they become:

```
val add = fn x => fn y => x+y
```

and

```
val add = fn xy =>
    case xy of
        (x,y) => x+y
```

So in the first case `add` is a function that takes an argument `x` and returns another function, which takes an argument `y` and then returns `x+y`. This technique of simulating multiple arguments by returning another function is known as currying.

In the second case `add` is a function that takes a tuple as an argument and then adds the two elements of the tuple.

This also explains the two different types. `->` is the function arrow, which associates to the right, meaning `int -> int -> int` is the same as `int -> (int -> int)` describing a function that takes an `int` and returns an `int -> int` function.

`*` on the other hand is the syntax used for tuple types, that is `int * int` is the type of tuples containing two ints, so `int * int -> int` (which is parenthesized as `(int * int) -> int` because `*` has higher precedence than `->`) describes a function that takes a tuple of two ints and returns an int.

Comment: Yes you are right. Found this useful article on currying in SML. https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse341/09au/notes/notes07.html

Answer (score 0):

The reason those 2 functions are different is because of the phenomenon of `Currying`. Specifically, Currying is the ability to write any function with `dom(f) = R^{n}` as a function that takes inputs from `R` `n`-times. This basically is accomplished by ensuring that each input returns a function for the next variable to take in. This is what the `->` sign represents - It's a fundamental result from the `Curry-Howard Isomorphism`. So :

```
fun addCurry x y = x + y (* int -> int -> int *)
fun addProd (x,y) = x + y (* (int*int) -> int *)
```

tells us that `addCurry` is the reduction of `addProd` into a form that can be used to "substitute" and return variables. So, `addProd` and `addCurry` are Contextually-Equivalent. However, they are *not* Semantically-Equivalent. 
`(int*int)` is a product-type. It says that it expects `input1=int` and `input2=int`. `int -> int` says that it takes an `int` and returns an `int`. It's an arrow-type.

If you're interested, you may also want to know that there are only 2 kinds of arguments to SML functions :

1) Curried

2) Tuples - So, `fun addProd (x,y)` represents `(x,y)` as a tuple to the function argument.